# aciTree поиск по дереву

Tags: jquery

Нужно выполнить поиск по дереву. Используется библитека `aciTree`.

пытаюсь заставить работать метод `.searchId` `http://acoderinsights.ro/source/aciTree/documentation.html#.searchId`

Проблема в том что метод не ищет по дочерним веткам, хотя в доке указано что должен.
Вот код:

```
function searchNodesTree() {
    var api = $('#tree-categories').aciTree('api'),
        options = {
            success: function (item, options) {
                console.log(item);
                option = {
                    success: function (item, options) {},
                    fail: function (item, options) {}
                };

                api.check(item, option)
            },
            fail: function (item, options) {console.log('fail')},
            id: '83657/83710'
        };

    checked = api.searchId(true, true , options);
}
```